# Unable to clear text from a Multi-Line Textbox from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm having a strange behaviour of a form. I have a Multi-line textbox in an Update panel an has a trigger which is a button click. Now on code behind if a condition is not met i'm trying to clear the text string in the textbox but its not.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updTxtGen" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"> 
   <ContentTemplate> 
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtGenVVOE" name= "txtGenVVOE"  TextMode="MultiLine" 
                                                runat="server"  style="font-size: 11px" rows="4" cols="55" Width="324px"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnCreateNote" EventName="Click" />     
       </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

here is my code behind from the button btnCreateNote

```
      else if (carryOn == -1 && chkBoxVal == false && vvoeStatus == "Completed")
            {
                lblVVOE2.Text = " VVOE Already Completed";
                txtGenVVOE.Text = string.Empty;
                txtGenVVOE.ReadOnly = true;
                btnCreateNote.Enabled = false;
                btnCopy.Enabled = false;


            }
```

Now everything is firing except the fact that the txtGenVVOE.Text is not set to empty nor does the .ReadOnly gets kicked in.. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try txtGenVVOE.Text = "";

Comment: Tried that before , did not work either, its strange that its working on other forms but not on this..

Comment: What happens if you remove `TextMode="MultiLine"` - does the clear work in that case?

Comment: I see you use UpdatePanels. Are you sure that the update panel, which contains txtGenVVOE gets refreshed?

Comment: @jods I think you have it, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.updatemode.aspx.  He has to call update on the panel.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.update.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try to update the updatepanel in the code behind and see it it works, Yuriy - I tried removing multiline and still did not work. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

You used an update panel, so you should update it to change the text box values

```
txtGenVVOE.Text = String.Empty;
updTxtGen.Update();
```

Cheers!